# Automated Build - image without source files

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I would like to create a docker image through Automated build on GitHub commit. My project structure

```
/src
/build
project.json
Gruntfile
Dockerfile
```

To build the project I have to:

```
npm install
grunt release
```

How can I configure Docker Hub to perform the build and create an image based on *build* folder (without sources)

Comment: See documentation: https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/

Comment: I've seen it many times but I still don't know how to build an image and ensure that source files are not included.

Comment: Ahhhh, now I understand. In Java world we use a Maven repository to hold the built artifacts. Creating a container (without source) is then simply a matter of using a ADD directive pointing at a repository URL